# method synchronization in UI automation using Geb+Spock+Gradle+groovy

Tags: multithreading, gradle, groovy, synchronization, geb

**Background** : I am using Geb+Spock+ Gradle for UI Test automation and using build.gradle file
which contains following config:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    maxParallelForks = 2
    forkEvery = 1
    include '**/*TestSuite*.class'
}
```

now,there are two suites ->

- TestSuite1.class

  and
- TestSuite2.class

  both are running in parallel using multiForking with the help of above config.

Both suite contains UI testcases which intend to verify the status of a payment on a Sandbox,

**Actual Problem** :Sandbox allow only 1 login at a time (session expires if other thread try to verify the payment status)

I want to run the payment verification method in a synchronized way so that payment verification could be done by one thread at a time(while other thread waits).

Regards
Niks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for the example you showed, Gradle works in a way that it starts a new JVM, a separate process, for every TestSuite. This means that this is not a multithreading problem, but a rather a process synchronization problem.

You will need to create some kind of lock for your processes.
The most basic way that I can think of is creating a lock directory on the file system.

Write a utility method, that checks if the lock directory is present, and if it is, wait for it to disappear to continue.
If the directory is not present, create the directory.
Then access the payment sandbox, only if you have created the directory.

Be aware that there might be a race condition, depending on your implementation.
But it should not be a problem in practice. Since UI tests are rather slow, you will probably not be requesting in a frequency high enough to ever notice it.